# How to get the index of a gson object?

Tags: kotlin, gson

I need to get the index of the array  containing the member fileName = "Andres"

```
data class File(var fileName: String, var _id : String? = null)
data class Files(val files: Array<File>)

val miObjetG = Gson().fromJson(response_files, Files::class.java)
var indice = miObjetG.files.filterIndexed { index, file -> file.fileName == "Andres"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [indexOfFirst](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) is what you are looking for:

```
val index = miObjetG.files.indexOfFirst{ it.fileName == "Andres" }
```

Comment: Thanks @thorin86 I have used your instructions and it works fine.